# How can I set awk delimiter to either string or character?

Tags: linux, awk, delimiter

How to use a **`string`** and another **`character`** as simultaneous delimiters in awk?

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C/SO$ echo "111:222text333:444" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
222text333

sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C/SO$ echo "111:222text333:444" | awk -F "text" '{print $2}'
333:444
```

So the question is, how can we use "`text`" and "`:`" as delimiters at the same time, so that `{print $2}` will print `222` as output? Consider input as in the examples above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple alternation

```
$ echo "111:222text333:444" | awk -F "text|:" '{print $2}'
222
```

**What it does**

- `-F "text|:"`  sets the field seperator as `text` or `:`

**Test**

To ensure that this correctly delimits the fields

```
$echo "111:222text333:444" | awk -F "text|:" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
111 222 333 444
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use `|` as delimitter, escape the `|` as

```
$ echo "111:222text333:444|hello" | awk -F '\\||text|:' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
111 222 333 444 hello
```

Comment: Thanks! 1 doubt, what if i need to have '|' as well as one more character as delimiter?

Comment: For example: echo "111|222text333|444" | awk -F "text|\|" '{print $3}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'

Comment: @A.M.D Good question. Escape the `|` and make sure you wrap the entire thing in single quotes. I have edited the answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @A.M.D You are always welcome :) Glad to hear I was of some help.:)